# Best way to add a face if I modeled the body first?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a character and am pretty far into it. I modeled the body first though and the face is in the center of the body (it's a cartoonish character). This means I'm gonna have to mess with the vertices in the center of the body to make the face. Can I make a face and then add it to the face or should I move the bodys vertices to make y face? I'm new to all of this so help from those of you is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it depends on your level of detail. If your face is mostly a texture and you can get the geometry you need by just moving vertices around on the body, then I would take that route.

But if you need to add significant amounts of geometry, then you will need to change your body geometry to keep good topology. See this article from [cg cookie](https://web.archive.org/web/20150612130444/https://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/11/28/why-topology-matters-modeling/).

Topology (basically having your edges flow cleanly) is important for animation and texturing. Too keep good topology you will probably need to modify your body's geometry. Whether you want to split edges as needed and keep the body mesh, or just start over with a new face mesh, is up to you.